# JFTP: :write: Bad response Could not save data. Error: Could not write to the configuration file

Tags: joomla2.5

JFTP: :write: Bad response
Could not save data. Error: Could not write to the configuration file

This error is shown when I upload files in joomla.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could disable ftp connection from global configuration at:

```
System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Ftp Settings -> Enable FTP: No
```

Or you could update with your ftp details (FTP Host / FTP Username / FTP Password / FTP Root).

If details doesn't get saved you have to do it manually downloading configuration.php and updating:

```
  public $ftp_host = '';
  public $ftp_port = '';
  public $ftp_user = '';
  public $ftp_pass = '';
  public $ftp_root = '';
  public $ftp_enable = '0'; // 0 for disable, 1 for enable
```

Good Luck!